# How to Calculate Time between two events in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following schema.

```
   Date          Time          Event_Type
2018-02-12    02:32:00 AM     Session_Start
2018-02-12    03:15:00 AM        event
2018-02-12    04:05:00 AM     Session_Start
2018-02-12    10:10:00 AM        event
2018-02-12    10:15:00 AM        event
2018-02-12    10:25:00 AM        event
2018-02-13    02:32:00 PM     Session_Start
2018-02-13    03:15:00 PM        event
2018-02-13    04:05:00 AM     Session_Start
```

I want to calculate the time a user spends during a particular session. So, a session duration is between the Session_start and the last event before the next Session_Start.

I thought of putting Session_Start as a group using the following command:

```
WITH grps AS (
  SELECT Date, Time, Event_Type, 
    COUNTIF(Event_Type = 'Session_Start') OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Time) grp
  FROM `project.events`
)
```

But this seems useless unless I find out a way to get to the event before the session_start. Any one have an idea what can be done in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track.  Then you want aggregation.  If your date/time were in a single `datetime` column, you would do:

```
WITH grps AS (
      SELECT datetime, Event_Type, 
             COUNTIF(Event_Type = 'Session_Start') OVER (ORDER BY datetime) as grp
      FROM `project.events`
     )
SELECT min(datetime), max(datetime),
       datetime_diff(min(datetime), max(datetime), second) as seconds_diff
FROM grps
GROUP BY grp;
```

If your date/time values are strings, you can do:

```
WITH grps AS (
      SELECT parse_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p', concat(date, ' ', time) ) as datetime, Event_Type, 
             COUNTIF(Event_Type = 'Session_Start') OVER (ORDER BY datetime) as grp
      FROM `project.events`
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the Date Time in single column and tried the first query but its giving me this error. **No matching signature for function DATETIME_DIFF for argument types: TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME, DATETIME, DATE_TIME_PART) **

Comment: @vsr . . . If your columns are timestamps, then use `timestamp_diff()` instead of `datetime_diff()`.