# How to use BigQuery Analytic Functions to calculate time between timestamped rows?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data set that represents analytics events like:

```
Row     timestamp   account_id  type     
1   2018-11-14 21:05:40 UTC abc start    
2   2018-11-14 21:05:40 UTC xyz another_type     
3   2018-11-26 22:01:19 UTC xyz start    
4   2018-11-26 22:01:23 UTC abc start    
5   2018-11-26 22:01:29 UTC xyz some_other_type
11  2018-11-26 22:13:58 UTC xyz start
...
```

With some number of account_ids. I need to find the average time between `start` records per `account_id`.

I'm trying to use analytic functions as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts). My end goal would be a table like:

```
Row     account_id     avg_time_between_events_mins
1     xyz     53
2     abc     47
3     pqr     65
...
```

my best attempt--based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874079/how-to-calculate-time-between-two-events-in-bigquery)--looks like this:

```
WITH
  events AS (
  SELECT
    COUNTIF(type = 'start' AND account_id='abc') OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as diff,
    timestamp
  FROM
    `myproject.dataset.events`
  WHERE
    account_id='abc')
SELECT
  min(timestamp) AS start_time,
  max(timestamp) AS next_start_time,
  ABS(timestamp_diff(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), MINUTE)) AS minutes_between
FROM
  events
GROUP BY
  diff
```

This calculates the time between each `start` event and the last non-`start` event prior to the next `start` event for a specific `account_id`.

I tried to use `PARTITION` and a `WINDOW FRAME CLAUSE` like this:

```
WITH
  events AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) as diff,
    timestamp
  FROM
    `myproject.dataset.events`
  WHERE
    type = 'start')
SELECT
  min(timestamp) AS start_time,
  max(timestamp) AS next_start_time,
  ABS(timestamp_diff(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), MINUTE)) AS minutes_between
FROM
  events
GROUP BY
  diff
```

But I got a nonsense result table. Can anyone walk me through how I would write and reason about a query like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need analytic functions for this:

```
select timestamp_diff(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), MINUTE)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from `myproject.dataset.events`
where type = 'start'
group by account_id;
```

This is the timestamp of the most recent minus the oldest, divided by one less than the number of starts.  That is the average between the starts.

Comment: Oh wow! I can't believe how simple and sensible that solution is. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SolomonBothwell - Agree, it is simple - but I really doubt it actually answers your question! I will believe you if you accept this answer. But in this case  - you will need to consider adjusting your question to match the answer :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . Is that because the proposed results have `row` column?

Comment: no. I think OP asked for average time between start and last non-start event before next start. while you answer average between starts. make sense? which is obviously simple task but require windowed functions

Comment: Sorry if my post was confusing. I'm asking for time between `start` events by account_id. I think @GordonLinoff's solution would need to be modified to first paritition by account_id

Comment: if you are looking for just average between starts - then you have answer (above) already :o) - I was confused by you mentioning `time between each start event and the last non-start event prior to the next start event for a specific account_id` in your question

Comment: @SolomonBothwell . . . The question explicitly says:  "I need to find the average time between  start records per account_id", which is what this answer does.